# Give an example where composite function is non-measurable

Tags: real-analysis

Give an example of a continuous function $g$ and a measurable function $h$ such that $h \circ g$ is non-measurable.

Answer (score 2):

If you are considering the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on the codomain of $g$ you won't find an example: in that case, if $g$ is continuous then it is measurable, and the composition of measurable functions is still measurable.

If you are considering the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets instead, there is an example: see the answer to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479441/example-of-a-continuous-function-that-is-not-measurable). You can check Wikipedia's article on the [Cantor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function) which the answerer calls the devil's staircase function.

The key to constructing that example lies first in the fact that the Cantor function maps a set of Lebesgue measure $0$ (the Cantor set) to the set of positive measure $[0,1]$ continuously, and secondly that every Lebesgue measurable set of positive measure contains a non-measurable set.

The cantor function is not injective, because it is almost everywhere constant. 
The addition of the identity $(f(x)=x)$ fixes that issue and makes it a continuous bijection with continuous inverse. From the argument in that answer it follows that its continuous inverse is non-measurable.

Note: I don't really see the role of the composition in your question, but once you find the non-measurable continuous function you could take $h$ to just be the identity.