# Does continuous imply measurable?

Tags: lebesgue-measure, examples-counterexamples

If $f$ is continuous, is it (Lebesgue) measurable ? Namely, $\{x\ :\ f(x)<\alpha\}\in\mathcal M\ \forall\alpha$ ?

If not what are some counter examples?

Comment: @John11 This question does not have a satisfying answer.

Comment: See here for a counterexample https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479441/example-of-a-continuous-function-that-is-not-lebesgue-measurable?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: In standard terminology $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is called Lebesgue measurable if the inverse image of every Borel set is Lebesgue measurable. With this definition the answer is surely 'yes'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the codomain $\sigma$-algebra considered is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra:

Yes it is Lebesgue measurable if continuous. You can show first that an upper (lower) semicontinuous function is measurable and then use the fact that a function that is both lower semicontinuous at upper semicontinuous at a point $x_0$ is continuous at that point.

In order to show that an upper (lower) semicontinuous function $f$ is measurable, show that $f^{-1}(]-\infty ,\alpha [)$ are closed and then the result would follow from the fact that closed sets are measurable.

Comment: The Lebesgue sigma algebra is not generated by open sets (this would be the Borel sigma algebra).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven  Thank you for the remark. I corrected my answer to specify when the proof works.