# Infinite product Lebesgue measure as the pushforward of 1-Lebesgue measure

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I want to construct a Borel map from the unit interval to the Hilbert cube $f: [0,1] \to [0, 1]^\mathbb N$ so that
\begin{equation}
\lambda \left(f^{-1}\left( \prod_{i \in \mathbb N} E_i\right)\right)= \prod_{i \in \mathbb N} \lambda(E_i)
\end{equation}
for $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure on the interval, $E_i \subseteq [0, 1]$ Borel, and $E_i = [0, 1]$ for all but finitely many indices. This gives the construction of the product measure without appealing to the Kolmogorov extension theorem (c.f. Tao's *An Introduction to Measure Theory* for the Kolmogorov approach to infinite product spaces). In the general case, I want to find a Borel map $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ so that 
\begin{equation}
\lambda \left(f^{-1}\left( \prod_{i \in \mathbb N} E_i\right)\right)= \prod_{i \in \mathbb N} \mu_i(E_i)
\end{equation}
for Radon probability measures $\mu_i$ on $\mathbb R$.

My initial thought was to try to encode the Hilbert cube into the dyadic intervals $[1/2^{n + 1}, 1/2^n]$, e.g. map these into the edges of the Hilbert cube, and try to construct measure preserving maps 
\begin{equation*}
[0, 1] \to \bigsqcup_{n \in \mathbb N} [0, 1] \to [0, 1]^{\mathbb N}.
\end{equation*}
The first map isn't too bad, however the second is more nebulous. The thought was that this has something to do with independent events in $[0, 1]$ representing a rectangle in the Hilbert cube, e.g. $A \times B \times [0, 1] \times \cdots$ gets pulled back to $A \cap B$.

My second thought was to construct a space-filling curve in spirit of showing the $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure $\lambda_d$ can be realised as the pushforward of $\lambda$ (c.f. [the discussion here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34982/are-there-space-filling-curves-for-the-hilbert-cube) for existence of a space filling curve and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2808597/pushing-lebesgue-measure-with-peano-curve) which states the Hilbert and Peano curves are measure preserving space filling curves).

The second seems a bit unwieldy but an approach that can work. The first seems more succinct but I can't get the details right. Moreover, the first seems more easy to generalize, i.e. if we replace $\lambda$ on the right hand side of our initial equation with Radon probability measures $\mu_i$ on $\mathbb R$ and the map into the Hilbert cube with a map $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ by considering the cumulative distribution functions of $\mu_i$.

Comment: If you let $X_n \in \{0,1\}$ denote the $n$-th digit in the binary expansion of $x \sim U([0,1))$, then the $X_n$ are iid uniformly distributed. This means that if $\Bbb{N} =\biguplus I_n$ is a disjoint partition with countably infinite sets $I_n$, and if you pick bijections $\iota_n : I_n \to \Bbb{N}$ and set $Y_n := \sum_{\ell =1}^\infty 2^{-\ell} X_{\iota_n^{-1}(\ell)}$, then the map $x \mapsto (Y_n(x))_n$ does what you want.

Comment: By the way, my greetings with the anniversary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much thought and cobbling everything I could find online and in the literature, I have finally arrived at a solution. We first show that every Radon probability measure $\mu$ on the real line is the pushforward of the Lebesgue measure on the unit interval. Set $g: [0, 1] \to \overline{\mathbb R}$ to be the [quantile function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function)
        \begin{equation} g(x) = \inf \big\{ p \in \mathbb R : \mu((-\infty, p]) \geq x) \big\}. \end{equation}
Note that $g$ is non-decreasing and, since the cumulative distribution function of $\mu$ is non-decreasing right continuous, the infimum is achieved. Thus, it satisfies $a < g(x)$ if and only if $\mu((-\infty, a]) < x$, and $g(x) \leq b$ if and only if $x \leq \mu((-\infty, b])$. In particular, 
        \begin{equation} g^{-1} ((a, b]) = (\mu((-\infty, a]), \mu((-\infty, b])], \end{equation}
    so $g$ is Borel and satisfies $\mu = \lambda \circ g^{-1}$ on the half-open intervals. Arguing by $\pi$-$\lambda$, we conclude $g$ is indeed the desired pushforward map. Let $g_n : [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ be the pushforward map corresponding to $\mu_n$, modified at the endpoints so that $g_n (0) = g_n (1) = 0$ in case they are infinite. This only adds finitely many points so the previous result still holds. Define the product map $\Psi: [0, 1]^{\mathbb N} \to {\mathbb R}^{\mathbb N}$ by $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N} \mapsto \{ g_n (x_n) \}_{n \in \mathbb N}$; notice that it pre-images rectangles to rectangles,
        \begin{equation} \Psi^{-1} \left( \prod_{n \in \mathbb N} E_n \right) = \prod_{n \in \mathbb N} g_n^{-1} (E_n) \end{equation}
    for any $E_n \subseteq \mathbb R$. This shows that $\Psi$ is Borel measurable and pushes the product Lebesgue measure onto the product of the Radon measures $\bigotimes_n \mu_n$. It remains then to find a Borel map $\Phi: [0, 1] \to [0, 1]^{\mathbb N}$ which pushes the Lebesgue measure forward to the product Lebesgue measure. Setting $f = \Psi \circ \Phi$ gives the result;
        \begin{equation} \lambda \left( f^{-1} \left( \prod_{n \in \mathbb N} E_n\right) \right) = \lambda \left( \Phi^{-1} \left(\prod_{n \in \mathbb N} g_n^{-1} (E_n) \right) \right) = \prod_{n \in \mathbb N} \lambda(g_n^{-1} (E_n)) = \prod_{n \in \mathbb N} \mu_n (E_n)  \end{equation}
    whenever $\prod_n E_n \in \prod_n \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$. Using a uniformly distributed space filling curve or the binary expansion argument as indicated by PhoemueX in the comments furnishes the desired $\Phi$.