# Howcome there is this simple counterexample to a result about measurable functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure, cantor-set, measurable-functions

There is a result that states:

If $\varphi$ is a measurable (in the sense that $\{x\ :\ \varphi(x)<\alpha\}\in\mathcal M\ \forall\alpha$) function, $f$ is a continuous function $\implies f\circ\varphi$  is measurable (but $\varphi\circ f$ is not necessarily measurable).

But if we take $\varphi(x)=x$ and $f$ a continuous non measurable function (Cantor's staircase function, or Cantor_function$(x)+x$ is we want it to be strictly increasing for whatever reason) then $f\circ\varphi=f$ is non measurable. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is a conflict between $f$ continuous $\implies f^{-1}(O)$ is open $\forall O$ open so measurable (since $f^{-1}(]-\infty,\alpha[ is open so a borel set so measurable), and the continuous but non measurable cantor function

Comment: Cantor's function is continuous, hence measurable.

Comment: @JohnCataldo The Cantor staircase function *is* measurable in the sense of the result you quote. There are two notions of measurability.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a continuous non-measurable function.

Comment: What is wrong with this example? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479441/example-of-a-continuous-function-that-is-not-lebesgue-measurable?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: That example is not measurable from $\cal L $ to $\cal L$, where $\cal L$ is the set of Lebesgue measurable sets.  But the definition in the OP (which is the usual definition in real analysis) is measurability $\cal L$ to $\cal B$, where $\cal B$ is the set of Borel sets.

Comment: @GEdgar: Isn't the usual definition in real analysis measurability $\mathcal B\to \mathcal B$? (Which also holds for continuous functions.)

Comment: "Measurable" for a real-valued function is with respect to whatever sigma-algebra is on the domain space (to the Borel sets in the reals).  If you are using Lebesgue measure on the real line for your domain, I would take it to mean the lebesgue-measurable sets.  Saying "measurable" when there is no measure is a bit strange (although common).

Answer (score 1):

When talking about measurability, we have to be very careful how we construe the domain and codomain.

There are two reasonable notions of measurable function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$:

- The preimage of every *measurable* set is measurable.
- The preimage of every *Borel* set is measurable. *(EDIT: and as GEdgar comments below, if one doesn't state otherwise the general assumption is that "measurable function" refers to this sense - which is why the fact you've quoted is simply stated for "measurable functions.")*

That is, in each case we think of the domain as equipped with the $\sigma$-algebra of measurable sets, but the codomain might be equipped with either of the $\sigma$-algebras of measurable sets or *Borel* sets. In one sense there are no continuous non-measurable functions, while in the other there are. See [this old MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479441/example-of-a-continuous-function-that-is-not-lebesgue-measurable) for details.

Your confusion comes because you're mixing two notions of measurability; the fact you quote in the question is true when we look at the codomain with the Borel algebra, while the existence of a continuous nonmeasurable function is true when we look at the codomain with the full algebra of measurable sets.

---

To wrap up a possible loose end: the definition you refer to doesn't mention a $\sigma$-algebra at all, it just talks about the preimages of open sets. But it's easy to show that if the preimage of every open set is measurable, then the preimage of every Borel set is measurable *since the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is generated by the open sets*. By contrast, the $\sigma$-algebra of measurable sets is vastly bigger, and so merely having measurable preimages of open sets doesn't in any way guarantee measurable preimages of measurable sets.

Comment: Furthermore, if you just say that a real-valued function is **measurable** with no extra explanation, you mean the second definition.

Answer (score 1):

We can only speak of a *continuous* function $X\to Y$ if $X$ and $Y$ are both topological spaces, hence are equipped with a topologies $\tau_X$ and $\tau_Y$.

Analogously we can only speak of a *measurable* function $X\to Y$ if $X$ and $Y$ are both measurable spaces, hence are equipped with a $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma_X$ and $\sigma_Y$.

If $f:X\to Y$ is continuous, then can we conclude that $f$ is measurable?

That depends on the question how these topologies and $\sigma$-algebras are related.

Commonly one works with $\sigma_X=\sigma(\tau_X)$ and $\sigma_X=\sigma(\tau_X)$ where $\sigma(\mathcal V)$ denotes the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\mathcal V$.

In that case $f$ can be shown to be measurable. This because it can be deduced in general that:$$f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal V))=\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal V))\tag1$$
For a proof of that see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1903402/75923).

Function $f$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}(\tau_Y)\subseteq\tau_X$ so that in that case: $$f^{-1}(\sigma_Y)=f^{-1}(\sigma(\tau_Y))=\sigma(f^{-1}(\tau_Y))\subseteq\sigma(\tau_X)=\sigma_X$$where the second equality is an application of $(1)$.

This states exactly that $f$ is measurable.

Answer (score 0):

A continuous function is always measurable, as you are talking about Lebesgue measure. This is because a function is continuous precisely when the sets  $\{f <\alpha\} $ are open.

Your function is an example of a function where some preimages of measurable sets are not measurable. But all preimages of Borel sets are measurable.

This assymetry, that we consider measurable sets in the domain and Borel  in the codomain, is due to integration. When  you want to define the Lesbesgue integral, you notice that you  need a notion of "near" in the codomain (to take limits), but in the domain you only need measurability.

Comment: The cantor staircase function is continuous and non measurable isn't it?

Comment: No. Every continuous function is measurable according to the definition  you gave.

Comment: Oh, so what's the alternative definition that allows for continuity and non measurability?

Comment: When you require, instead of having measurable preimages of open sets (or Borel, it's the same), having measurable preimages of measurable sets.