# How to prove Cantor function is a measurable function?

Tags: real-analysis

I know that Cantor function $\varphi$ is not a measurable funtion. Also I understand that we can prove it by showing $g(x)=x+\varphi(x)$ is not a measurable function. But I don't know how can we prove it by the definition of measurable function.

Comment: But if $\varphi$ is a measurable function,then $x+\varphi$ should be a measurable function while it's not.So is there something I misunderstand?

Comment: So far I'm not puzzled about that. If continuous function is measurable. Let's see the function $g^{-1}(x)$,it's continous but not measurable because the preimage of a measure zero is a non-meansurable set(Consider a nonmeasurable set in the $g(C)$,C is cantor set).So I don't think that a continous function must be measurable.

Comment: @qbert This comes up periodically on MSE; see, e.g., [MSE 479441](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/479441).

Comment: The key here is that "measurable" if otherwise unqualified generally means $(\mathbb R, \mathcal L), (\mathbb R,\mathcal B)$ measurable. Not $(\mathbb R, \mathcal L), (\mathbb R,\mathcal L)$-measurable.

Comment: @BenjaminDickman I see, thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: @qbert you were right! If they actually mean $(\mathbb R,\mathcal L)-(\mathbb R,\mathcal L)$-measurable, they should say so. "It's continuous, so it's measurable" is a perfectly valid objection/answer to this question as currently written.

Comment: All continuous function are Borel Measurable &  Hence Measurable. Cantor function is continuous so it is Measurable too