# Is it true that if E is measurable set and f is continuous on E, $B \subseteq \Bbb R$ a measurable set, then $f^{-1}(B)$ measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Is it true that if E is measurable set and $f :E \to \Bbb R$ is continuous, $B \subseteq \Bbb R$ a measurable set, then $f^{-1}(B)$ is measurable set?

My guess: this is true.

Approach: Consider $\{A| f^{-1}(A) \text{is measurable}\}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing all open intervals.

Hence this is Borel sigma-algebra so $f^{-1}(B)$ is a Borel set and hence measurable.

As I got in the comment that the answer is not correct so please help me answering this question.

Comment: By a measurable set do you mean   a Borel set or a Lebesgue measurable set?

Comment: Lebesgue measurable set

Comment: Your argument is not correct. If  a sigma algebra contains all open intervals it contains all Borel sets but it need not contain Lebesgue measurable sets.

Comment: Then how to do that?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479441/example-of-a-continuous-function-that-is-not-lebesgue-measurable