# Does $\mathcal P ( \mathbb R ) \otimes \mathcal P ( \mathbb R ) = \mathcal P ( \mathbb R \times \mathbb R )$?

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, cardinals

Obviously the answer's yes if I replace $\mathbb R$ by a countable set.

If $\mathbb R$ is replaced by a set $X$ having a greater cardinality, then the diagonal $\{ (x,x) , \ x\in X\}$ is not in the product $\sigma$-field (see for instance http://david.efnet-math.org/?p=16) so the answer is no.

Comment: What does $\otimes$ mean here?

Comment: It means the product sigma-algebra.  Next question: $\mathcal P$ means the power set.

Comment: See an answer in mathoverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/a/115024/454  (YES with continuum hypothesis, but independent of ZFC)

Comment: $X$ and $\{(x,x)\mid x\in X\}$ *always* have the same size. I suspect this is a typo, and rather than mentioning diagonals, you just meant to say that $|X|>|\mathbb R|$ (as in Nedoma's result).

Comment: (I've removed the tag cardinals, which seems irrelevant. The tag set-theory seems related, in view of Gerald's comment and link. Feel free to revert if you don't think the change is appropriate.)

Comment: @user104310 now you can answer your question and later accept it

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I add a coma after the word cardinality, I hope it is clear now that I meant "if X has cardinality greater than $\mathbb R$".

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Andres: Perhaps [descriptive-set-theory] is somewhat of a better fit?

Comment: @Asaf It's hard to tell just by looking at the question.  I haven't looked into the answers yet, but I would guess that the "yes" answer under CH is less descriptive-set-theoretical and the consistency of the "no" answer is more descriptive-set-theoretical.  Anything whose answer is independent of ZFC seems, after the fact, to be a good candidate for the "set theory" tag I think :-)

Comment: @Trevor: I see. I suppose that both tags can live in harmony, in case that you're right about that and someone posts a full answer (full = some outline of what and how things can go wrong when the answer is "no", with references maybe).

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I put the cardinals tag back, I think it is definitely relevant.

Comment: Sure, sorry for the distraction.

Answer (score 8):

Firstly let me mention that as far as integration theory 
and probability theory are concerned, I don't think 
my question is an interesting one. I was asked this by a student, 
I realized I didn't know the answer, nor did any of
my colleagues, so asked it here out of curiosity.

Let me summarize the information I could get so far. 
First observe that whether
$$ 
\mathcal P ( E ) \otimes \mathcal P ( E ) = \mathcal P ( E \times E ) 
$$
or not depends only on the cardinality of $E$.

The answer is obviously yes when $E$ is countable for $E \times E$ is also countable so every subset of $E\times E$ is a countable union of singletons, hence in the product $\sigma$-algebra.

The answer's no if $\vert E \vert > 2^{\aleph_0}$, as is explained 
[there](http://david.efnet-math.org/?p=16).

My question was: what happens in between?

It was proved by Rao that the answer's yes if $\vert E\vert=\aleph_1$. Let me sketch his (very nice) argument, some knowledge about 
[ordinals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number) is required to understand it. 
Consider the property, for a set $E$, of having a sequence of countable partitions that separate points: there exists a family $(A_{i,j})_{i,j\in \mathbb N}$ of subsets of $E$ such that

- For every $i\in \mathbb N$, the sequence $(A_{i,j})_{j\in \mathbb N}$ is a partition of $E$.
- For every $x\neq y$ in $E$, there exists $(i,j)$ such that $x\in A_{i,j}$ and $y\not\in A_{i,j}$.

Clearly $\mathbb R$ has this property (given an integer $i$, there is a partition of $\mathbb R$ into countably many intervals of length $1/i$). The smallest uncountable ordinal $\omega_1$ can be mapped to $\mathbb R$ in a one to one way, so it also has this property (incidentally I wonder if there's a way to prove this directly, say avoiding the axiom of choice).

Now if a set $E$ has this property, graphs belong to the product $\sigma$-field. By graph, I mean the graph of a function 
$f \colon F \to E$
where $F$ is a subset of $E$. Indeed, if $f$ is such a function then its graph equals
$$
\bigcap_{i\in \mathbb N} \bigcup_{j\in \mathbb N} f^{-1} ( A_{i,j} ) \times A_{i,j} .
$$ 
A subset of $E\times E$ whose every vertical section is countable is a countable union of graphs, so it also belongs to the product $\sigma$-field, and so does a subset whose every horizontal section is countable.

Lastly, consider 
$\{ (\alpha, \beta ) , \ \beta \leq \alpha \in\omega_1\}$,
the below diagonal subset of $\omega_1 \times\omega_1$. 
Its vertical section above any given $\alpha\in \omega_1$ is 
$\{ \beta \in \omega_1 ,\ \beta \leq \alpha\} = \alpha +1$ which is countable. In the same way, every horizontal section of the above diagonal subset of $\omega_1\times \omega_1$ is countable. Therefore, every subset of $\omega_1 \times \omega_1$ can be written as the union of a set whose vertical sections are countable and a set whose horizontal section are countable, finishing the proof of
$$ 
\mathcal P ( \omega_1 ) \otimes \mathcal P ( \omega_1 ) = 
\mathcal P ( \omega_1 \times \omega_1 ) .
$$

So far, the answer to the original question is thus yes if $\vert E \vert \leq \aleph_1$ and no if $\vert E \vert > 2^{\aleph_0}$. So under the continuum hypothesis: $\aleph_1 = 2^{\aleph_0}$ the question is completely solved.

Now, what if we do not assume CH? Apparently, it is shown 
[there](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~miller/res/hier.pdf)
that there is a model of ZFC in which spaces of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ fail to have the property, but I'm afraid the paper is too much of logic and model theory for me.

To conclude, I think this is the first time I was posed an undecidable question by a student.

Comment: To answer your question about whether the Axiom of Choice is needed to get a countable sequence of partitions of $\omega_1$ that separates points, it is. This is because it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ (plus Dependent Choice, even) that $\omega_1$ is a measurable cardinal, in which case there would be a measure-one set of points that could not be distinguished by any of the partitions.

Answer (score 4):

This problem appears in Kunen's thesis (1968). I mentioned it a few months back, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455797/unprovability-results-in-zfc/455929#455929)