# Counterexample to "Measurable in each variable separately implies measurable"

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, examples-counterexamples

Some fellow classmates are preparing for a qualifying exam on real analysis, and asked me for help on the following question:

> Let $ \ f:[0,1]^2\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be such that:
>
> (i) $\ f(x,\cdot)$ is measurable for each fixed $x\in[0,1]$;
>
> (ii) $\ f(\cdot,y)$ is continuous for each fixed $y\in[0,1]$.
>
> Show that $\ f$ is measurable.  If we only assume that $\ f(\cdot,y)$ is *measurable* for each $y\in[0,1]$, rather than continuous, can we still conclude that $f$ is measurable?

I was able to come up with the following simple proof (at least I hope it is a proof) of the first statement using some standard arguments:

> *Proof.* $ \ $ Define a sequence of functions $\{f_n:[0,1]^2\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}\}_{n\geq 1}$ by:
>
> $$ f_n(x,y)=f\bigg(\frac{i}{n},y\bigg), \qquad \text{for } x\in\bigg[\frac{i}{n},\frac{i+1}{n}\bigg], \ i=1,\cdots,n $$
>
> Moreover, since $ \ f(\cdot,y)$ is continuous at $x=\tfrac{i}{n}$ for each $y$, for each $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta_y>0$ so that
>
> $$ \bigg| \ x-\frac{i}{n}\bigg|<\delta_y \qquad\Rightarrow\qquad \bigg| \ f(x,y)-f\bigg(\frac{i}{n},y\bigg)\bigg|<\epsilon; $$
>
> therefore, for any $n>\tfrac{1}{\delta_y}$ and any fixed $(x,y)\in[0,1]^2$ with $x\in\big[\tfrac{i}{n},\tfrac{i+1}{n}\big]$, we have
>
> $$ \bigg| \ x-\frac{i}{n}\bigg|\leq \frac{1}{n}<\delta_y $$
>
> and so
>
> $$ | \ f_n(x,y)-f(x,y)|=\bigg| \ f\bigg(\frac{i}{n},y\bigg)-f(x,y)\bigg|<\epsilon. \tag{$\ast$} $$
>
> In other words, $ \ f_n\longrightarrow f$ pointwise.  Furthermore, we clearly have that
>
> $$ A_n:=\{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2 \ | \ f_n(x,y)>\alpha\} \qquad\qquad\qquad $$
>
> $$ \qquad\qquad \ =\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1}\bigg(\bigg[\frac{i}{n},\frac{i+1}{n}\bigg)\times \bigg\{y\in[0,1] \ \bigg| \ \ f\bigg(\frac{i}{n},y\bigg)>\alpha \bigg\}\bigg). $$
>
> Since $ \ f\big(\tfrac{i}{n},\cdot\big)$ is measurable for each $i=1,\cdots,n$, the latter expression is a union of measurable sets.  This means that $ \ A_n$ is measurable, and therefore $ \ f_n$ is measurable for each $n\geq 1$.  Finally, as the limit of measurable functions is measurable, we conclude that $ \ f$ is measurable.
>
> $\hspace{6.25in}\square$

I'm fairly certain that the above proof is correct (**anyone care to confirm?**); however, that still leaves the following:

> **Question:  If $ \ f$ is merely measurable in each variable separately, is it measurable?**

The proof I gave above uses the continuity assumption in $(\ast)$, so obviously the same proof will not work in this case, but I cannot come up with any counterexamples.  Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want an example using Lebesgue measure: There are non-measurable subsets of the plane having at most two points in common with any line. c.f. Gelbaum and Olmsted, *Counterexamples in Analysis*, pg. 142. Take the characteristic function of such a set.

Comment: Just a helpful remark: a function satisfying (i),(ii) is widely known as a *Caratheodory function*.

Comment: A made a couple of remarks on this here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/590251/non-measurable-set-in-product-sigma-algebra-s-t-every-section-is-measurable/621772#621772

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> If $f$ is merely measurable in each variable separately, is it measurable?

Not necessarily.

For a counterexample, fix some non measurable subset $E$ of $[0,1]$ and define $f(x,y)=0$ for every $(x,y)$ in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ with the exception that $f(x,x)=1$ if $x$ is in $E$.

Then, for every $x$, either $f(x,\ )=0$ everywhere or $f(x,\ )=0$ everywhere except at $x$, hence $f(x,\ )$ is measurable. Likewise for $f(\ ,y)$, for every $y$ in $[0,1]$.

But, if $f$ was measurable, considering the measurable function $g:x\mapsto(x,x)$, one would get a measurable function $f\circ g$ on $[0,1]$. Since $f\circ g=\mathbf 1_E$ is not measurable, $f$ is not measurable.

Comment: Excellent, I figured that it would be something along those lines, but couldn't quite pin it down.  Thanks!

Comment: But $f$ is zero except on a null set. Doesn't that make it measurable?

Comment: @TonyK Depends on the sigma-algebra one considers, Borel or Lebesgue.

Comment: For $f$ measurable and $g$ measurable, how do we know that $f\circ g$ is measurable?

Comment: @yoyostein Using the appropriate sigma-algebras, this is direct, no?

Comment: I see, I was concerned that "composition of two Lebesgue-measurable functions is not necessarily Lebesgue-measurable".

Answer (score 0):

This is not because a fuction takes the values $0$ and $1$ that we can declare it is measurable; her, the partial functions of $f$ are not. Fix $y$. The set of points $x$ such that the first partial function $x\mapsto f(x,y)$ is less than $1$ equals $E\setminus \lbrace y\rbrace$, which is not measurable. Thus $f$ is not separately measurable. 
  J. Yeh in his "Real analysis, theory of measure and integration", 3ed edition, Appandix E, proves that these functions, i.e., separately measurable functions, are measurable. But I am not sure if his proof is correct...

Comment: Yeh's proof is correct. But the concept of $X_i$-section that Yeh considers in Appendix E is not the same as the concept of $x_i$-section. For simplicity, consider a product of two factors $X_1 \times X_2$. Consider $E \subseteq X_1 \times X_2$. 

Given $x_1 \in X_1$, the $x_1$-section of $E$ is $E(x_1) = \{x_2 \in X_2 : (x_1,x_2) \in E\}$. Given $x_2 \in X_2$, the $x_2$-section of $E$ is $E(x_2) = \{x_1 \in X_1 : (x_1,x_2) \in E\}$. 


The $X_1$-section of $E$ is $E[X_1] =  \{x_1 \in X_1 : (x_1,x_2) \in E \text{ for some 
 }x_2 \in X_2\} = \bigcup_{x_2 \in X_2} E(x_2)$.

Comment: Thanks for your remark. I will reread his theorem.