# How to show, that a function defined on a product $\sigma$-algebra is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Consider measurable spaces $(A_1,\mathcal{A}_1)$, $(A_2,\mathcal{A}_2)$ and their product $\sigma$-algebra $(A_1\times A_2,\mathcal{A}_1\otimes \mathcal{A}_2)$. I want to show, that

$$f:A_1\times A_2\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$$

is measurable. Is it sufficient, to show that for any $a_1\in A_1$, $a_2\in A_2$ the functions

$$f(\cdot,a_2):A_1\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$$

$$f(a_1,\cdot):A_2\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$$

are measurable?

Comment: It is not sufficient, see David Mitra's comment to the question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/647235/27978 (the book referenced, Gelbaum and Olmsted, "Counterexamples in Analysis" is well worth having in your library if real analysis is your thing).