# Example of Non-Measurable Sets in Product Space

Tags: measure-theory, examples-counterexamples, product-space

If $\mu$ and $\nu$ are measures on $X$ and $Y$, is there an example of a set $E\subset X\times Y$ such that $E_x,E^y$ are measurable for all $(x,y)$ but $E$ is not measurable with respect to $\mu\times\nu$?

Comment: Potential duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/590251/non-measurable-set-in-product-sigma-algebra-s-t-every-section-is-measurable?rq=1