# Product of Borel $\sigma$-algebras vs Borel $\sigma$-algebra of product

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

If $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces with associated Borel $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{B}_X$ and $\mathcal{B}_Y$, then the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}_X\otimes \mathcal{B}_Y\subset \mathcal{B}_{X\times Y}$, $X\times Y$ with the product topology. If $X$ and $Y$ are separable metric then equality holds. What is an example when the inclusion is strict?

Comment: See my [5 May 2002 sci.math.research post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=1691283). I'm not sure if your specific question is answered there (I don't have time right now to check), but even if it doesn't, it should give you enough leads to find an answer.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/39882/product-of-borel-sigma-algebras

Comment: Great refs all.

Answer (score 0):

Take $X=Y=\mathbb 2^R$, embedded with the discrete topology. The topology is Hausdorff, so $\{(x,x)\in X \times X\}$ is closed, and hence in $B_{X\times Y}$, And yet it is not in $B_X \otimes B_Y$

Comment: This isn't right. Like you said, the diagonal is closed so it is in the sigma algebra generated by (even) open rectangles. In fact, the answer here (due to Kunen) is that this independent of ZFC. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455797/unprovability-results-in-zfc/455929#455929

Comment: Your example will work if you replace $\mathbb{R}$ by any set of higher cardinality with the diagonal as a witness.

Comment: My bad. Anyway, ive editted the comment

Comment: I think your answer will be more helpful if you also add an explanation for why the diagonal fails to be in $B_X \otimes B_X$.