# Sigma-algebra generated by the generalized rectangles

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

A generalized rectangle is $A\times B$ where $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\Bbb R.$ Is the $\sigma$-algebra $S$  on $\Bbb R^2$, generated by the set of all generalized rectangles, equal to the set of all subsets of $\Bbb R^2\;$?

I suspect not. Identify $\Bbb R$ with the cardinal ordinal $2^{\omega}$ and let $T=\{(a,b): a\in b\in 2^{\omega}\}.$ I suspect that $T\not \in S.$ I worked on this  but I feel that I am stuck, perhaps on something obvious.

Comment: See [on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/275375/7206). I'm almost sure there is a local duplicate of this question, too.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455797/unprovability-results-in-zfc/455929#455929

Comment: @AsafKaragila      I just recently recalled this Q from American Mathematical Monthly  (Problems section) circa 1970....  I  had no idea it would be undecidable in ZFC